# ajax call not sending to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My ajax call won't send to php file for it to show on screen. The call is running because i get the "ok" alert but the php page does not show the hello world on the screen

```
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {data: "hello world"},
        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });


    $test = 7;
    echo $test;
    $data = "";
    $data = $_POST["data"]; 
    $request = $data;

    print_r($request);
    echo $request;
```

expected: 7hello world
actual: 7

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Because AJAX call is asynchronous, so after $.ajax it jump to  $test = 7

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: You do not have any code that prints the ajax response on screen. In the success method, the function should have data like success: function(data) and then instead of alert OK, do alert(data).

Comment: Here `success: function()` change this to `success: function(data)` and print your value like this -> `console.log(data)` .

Answer (score 2):

You need a callback in your function ..  IE

```
success: function(result){
```

This will end up with the output of the `php` file, and can be used like so:

```
alert("OK - " + result);
// OR
console.log(result);
// OR
$('#your_element_id').html(result);
```